# Hadoop Cluster on Docker Swarm - Datanodes Failed to Connect to Namenode

Tags: docker, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, nodes, docker-swarm

I am new to Docker and trying to build a Hadoop cluster with Docker Swarm. I tried to build it with docker compose and it worked perfectly. However, I would like to add other services like Hive, Spark, HBase to it in the future so a Swarm seems a better idea.

When I tried to run it with a version 3.7 yaml file, the namenode and datanodes started successfully. But when I visited the web UI, it showed that there is no nodes available at the "Datanodes" tab (neither at the "Overview" tab). It seems the datanodes failed to connect to the namenode. I had checked the port of each node with `netstat -tuplen` and both 7946 and 4789 worked fine.

Here is the yaml file I used:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  namenode:
    image: flokkr/hadoop:latest
    hostname: namenode
    networks:
      - hbase
    command: ["hdfs","namenode"]
    ports:
      - target: 50070
        published: 50070
      - target: 9870
        published: 9870
    environment:
      - NAMENODE_INIT=hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /
      - ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR=/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name
    env_file:
      - ./compose-config
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

  datanode:
    image: flokkr/hadoop:latest
    networks:
      - hbase
    command: ["hdfs","datanode"]
    env_file:
      - ./compose-config
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

volumes:
  namenode:
  datanode:

networks:
  hbase:
    name: hbase
```

Basically I just update the yaml file from [this repo](https://github.com/flokkr/docker-hadoop) to version 3.7 and tried to run it on GCP. And [here](https://github.com/simcheuk/docker-hadoop-flokkr) is my repo in case you want to replicate the case.

And this is the status of ports of the manager node:
[image]

the worker node:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you implementing and deploying your own cluster using VM machines on GCP with Docker and Docker compose? Also, which web UI are talking about ?

Comment: Yes! Here is what I was doing with GCP. First I used docker machine (driver: google) to create 3 instances on GCP (1 manager 2 workers). Then I used docker stack deploy with the yaml file above to implement the hadoop cluster. And I was referring to the port 9870 web UI of the manager node. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a network related issue, the pods are up an running but they are not registering on your Web GUI maybe the network communication it's not reaching between them. Check your internal firewall rules and OS firewall, run some network test on the specific ports.